# How can I complete the proof of Noetherianity of I. S. Cohen?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, finitely-generated

Theorem (I. S. Cohen).

If $R$ is an unital commutative ring, and for each ideal prime $\mathfrak{p}\in Spec(R)$ we know $\mathfrak{p}$ is finitely-generated as $R$-mod then $R$ is Noetherian.

Proof.

We use the Zorn's Lemma.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ $:=$ ${\lbrace{\mathfrak{a}\in\mathcal{I}deals(R)\mid \mathfrak{a}\neq R \wedge \mathfrak{a} \text{ is not finitely-generated as }R\text{-mod}}\rbrace}$.

Now we reason by reductio ad absurdum.

Let $\mathcal{C}\neq\emptyset$.

Now for any ascendent (in the inclusion sense) chain of ideals $C\in\mathcal{C}$ where $C={\lbrace C_i \rbrace}_{i \in I}$ for some set of indexes $I$, we have that $\bigcup C$ is a proper ideal of $R$, and $\bigcup C \in \mathcal{C}$, because it is not, the finite set of generators of $\bigcup C$ was into some ideal of the chain, we say $C_{i_0}$, and this ideal of the chain was finitely-generated as $R$-mod. Absurd. Then $\bigcup C$ is not finitely-generated as $R$-mod, then $\bigcup C \in \mathcal{C}$, and it is maximal for its chain. Then $\mathcal{C}$ is an inductive set. Let $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal in $\mathcal{C}$.

The following step is to use the fact that any ideal of $\mathcal{C}$ is not prime.
As $\mathfrak{m}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, it is not in $Spec(R)$, and if the proper ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is such that $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq \mathfrak{a}$ then $\mathfrak{a}$ is finitely-generated as $R$-mod.

Let $x,y\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ and $xy\in \mathfrak{m}$. They exist because the mentioned ideal is neccesarily non-prime. Then we can see that the ideals $\mathfrak{m}+{\langle x\rangle}_R$ is finitely-generated because contains strictily $\mathfrak{m}$. Let ${\langle\lbrace u_1,\ldots,u_n,x\rbrace\rangle}_R = \mathfrak{m}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$, where ${\lbrace u_1,\ldots,u_n\rbrace}\subseteq \mathfrak{m}$. In the other hand $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq \left( \mathfrak{m} : x\right)$ because $y \notin \mathfrak{m}$ and $y \in \left( \mathfrak{m} : x\right)$. Let ${\langle\lbrace v_1,\ldots,v_m,y\rbrace\rangle}_R = \left( \mathfrak{m} : x\right)$.

Now it is easy note that

$\langle \lbrace {\phantom{\rangle\lbrace}}u_1 v_1, u_1 v_2, \ldots ,u_1 v_m,u_1 y,$

$u_2 v_1, u_2 v_2, \ldots ,u_2 v_m,u_2 y,$

$\ldots \ldots,$

$u_n v_1, u_n v_2, \ldots ,u_n v_m,u_n y,$

$  x v_1,   x v_2, \ldots ,  x v_m,  x y {\phantom{\langle\lbrace} \rbrace \rangle}_R = \left( \mathfrak{m} + {\langle x \rangle}_R\right)\left( \mathfrak{m} : x\right) \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$

We can augment the set of generators,

$G := \lbrace {\phantom{\rangle\lbrace}} u_1 , u_2 , \ldots , u_{n-1} , u_n,$

$u_1 v_1, u_1 v_2, \ldots ,u_1 v_m,u_1 y,$

$u_2 v_1, u_2 v_2, \ldots ,u_2 v_m,u_2 y,$

$\ldots \ldots,$

$u_n v_1, u_n v_2, \ldots ,u_n v_m,u_n y,$

$  x v_1,   x v_2, \ldots ,  x v_m,  x y {\phantom{\lbrace} \rbrace}$

The only problem I have is that $\left( \mathfrak{m} + {\langle x \rangle}_R\right)\left( \mathfrak{m} : x\right) \subseteq {\langle G \rangle}_R \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$, but the reverse $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq {\langle G \rangle}_R$(?) is neccesary to complete the proof (I believe). If we would prove in some way that $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely-generated then we have obtained the contradicition that we expected, and then $\mathcal{C}=\emptyset$ and we can derive that $R$ is finitely-generated as $R$-mod.

I know something in front of me but I do not see. Some explanation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Theorem you mention is Theorem 3.4 in Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory. I provide a sketch of the given (very elegant) proof by Matsumura in the form of a hint:

Let $\Gamma$ be the set of ideals that are not finitely generated. If $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$ then we have a maximal element $I$ of $\Gamma$ and elements $x,y$ of the ring such that $x \not\in I, y \not\in I, xy \in I$. Now notice that the ideals $I+Ay$ and $(I:y)$ are finitely generated. Write $I+Ay=(u_1,\dots,u_m,y), (I:y) = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$. Can you now complete the proof? (i can provide further details upon request)

Edit:

More specifically, let $I+Ay = (\xi_1,\dots,\xi_m)$. Since $\xi_i \in I+Ay$ we can write $\xi_i = u_i + c_i y$ with $u_i \in I$. Then we see that $I+Ay=(u_1,\dots,u_m,y)$. Also $(I:y) = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$. Now let $z \in I$. Then $z = a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_m u_m + a y$. Hence $a \in (I:y)$ and so $a = d_1 v_1 + \cdots + d_n v_n$, which gives $z=a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_m u_m + d_1 v_1 y + \cdots + d_n v_n y$ and so $I=(u_1,\dots,u_m,yv_1,\dots,yv_n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think that I can complete the proof. Can I write the proof complete?

Comment: @EärendilElrondArwen: You can certainly write your own answer. Do you plan though to accept my answer?

Comment: Yes. I only want write the completion of your sketch. At the bottom I have written the completion. I would wish to have feedback on its correction or if it is simplificable.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem (I. S. Cohen).**

If $R$ is an unital commutative ring, and for each ideal prime $\mathfrak{p}\in Spec(R)$ we know $\mathfrak{p}$ is finitely-generated as $R$-mod then $R$ is Noetherian.

**Proof.**

We use the Zorn's Lemma.

First we build the set of all hipotetical ideals of $R$ that they are not finitely-generated as $R$-mod, that we will call $\mathcal{C}$.

$$\mathcal{C}:={\lbrace{\mathfrak{a}\in\mathcal{I}deals(R)\mid \mathfrak{a}\neq R \wedge \mathfrak{a} \text{ is not finitely-generated as }R\text{-mod}}\rbrace}$$

Then, the intersection of $\mathcal{C}$ and $Spec(R)$ is empty. $\mathcal{C} \cap Spec(R) = \emptyset$.

Now we reason by *reductio ad absurdum*.

Supossition : $\mathcal{C}\neq\emptyset$.

We go to undestand that if $\mathcal{C}\neq \emptyset$ then there exist some maximal ideal into $(\mathcal{C},\subseteq)$.

- For any ascendent (in the inclusion sense) chain of ideals $S\subset\mathcal{C}$ where $S={\lbrace S_i \rbrace}_{i \in I}$ for some set of indexes $I$, we have that $\bigcup S$ is a proper ideal of $R$.
- And $\bigcup S \in \mathcal{C}$, because if it is not, the finite set of generators of $\bigcup S$ was into some ideal of the chain, we say $S_{i_0}$ with $i_0 \in I$, and this ideal of the chain was finitely-generated as $R$-mod. Absurd. Then $\bigcup S$ is not finitely-generated as $R$-mod, then $\bigcup S \in \mathcal{C}$, and it is maximal for its chain.

Then $\mathcal{C}$ is an inductive set. There exists maximal ideals in $\mathcal{C}$ in the sense of inclusion of sets.

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal in $\mathcal{C}$.

Now we go to search (and finding) a pair of ideals related between them and with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that they are finitely-generated as $R$-mod, and then, using the fact that any ideal of $\mathcal{C}$ is not prime we will obtain a contradiction. The searched contradiction is that $\left(\mathfrak{m} \in \mathcal{C}\right) \wedge \left(\mathfrak{m} \notin \mathcal{C}\right)$.

As $\mathfrak{m}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$, it is not in $Spec(R)$, and if the proper ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ is such that $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq \mathfrak{a}$ then $\mathfrak{a}$ is finitely-generated as $R$-mod.

Let $x,y\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ and $xy\in \mathfrak{m}$. They exist because the mentioned maximal ideal is neccesarily non-prime.

- Now we realize that $\mathfrak{m} \subsetneq \left( \mathfrak{m} : {\langle x \rangle}_R \right)$ because $y \notin \mathfrak{m}$ and $y \in \left( \mathfrak{m} : {\langle x \rangle}_R \right)$. Then, there exists a finite subset $V$ of $\left( \mathfrak{m} : {\langle x \rangle}_R \right)$ such that ${\langle V \rangle}_R = \left( \mathfrak{m} : {\langle x \rangle}_R \right)$.
- In the other hand we see that ${\mathfrak{m}} \subsetneq {\mathfrak{m}}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$. Because of it, there exists a finite subset of ${\mathfrak{m}}$, I say $U$, such that ${\langle U \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \rangle}_R = {\mathfrak{m}}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$.

We go to prove that there exists a finite subset $U \subset \mathfrak{m}$ such that ${\langle U \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \rangle}_R = \mathfrak{m}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$. First we write a generator system for $\mathfrak{m}+{\langle x \rangle}_R = {\langle \lbrace w_1 , w_2 , \ldots , w_l \rbrace \rangle}_R$.

We can write this generators by the way of the sum of ideals where they are:
$\exists {\lbrace u_1 , u_2 , \ldots , u_l \rbrace} \subset \mathfrak{m}$ and $\exists {\lbrace a_1 , a_2 , \ldots , a_l \rbrace} \subset R$ such that $w_i = u_i + a_i x \; i = 1, 2 , \ldots , l$. Now we obtain ${u_i = w_i - a_i x \; i= 1 , 2 , \ldots , l}$ which if we take a minimal subset generator (join to $\lbrace x \rbrace$), we have got the set $U=\lbrace u_1 , u_2 , \ldots , u_n \rbrace$ sucht that $U \subset \mathfrak{m}$ and ${\langle U \cup \lbrace x \rbrace \rangle}_R = \mathfrak{m}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$.

Now:

$U = \lbrace u_1 , u_2 , \ldots , u_n \rbrace \subset \mathfrak{m} \;\; V = \lbrace v_1 , v_2 , \ldots , v_m \rbrace$

$z \in \mathfrak{m} \implies z \in \mathfrak{m}+{\langle x \rangle}_R$ then we have $z = r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2 + \ldots + r_n u_n + r_{n+1} x$.

As $\left( \;z = r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2 + \ldots + r_n u_n + r_{n+1} x \in \mathfrak{m} \right)$ $\; \wedge \;$ $\left( w := r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2 + \ldots + r_n u_n \in \mathfrak{m} \; \right) \; \implies \; z-w = r_{n+1} x \in \mathfrak{m}$ which again means that $r_{n+1} \in \left(\mathfrak{m}{:} {\langle x \rangle}_R \right)$.

Now $r_{n+1} = s_1 v_1 + s_2 v_2 + \ldots + s_m v_m$ and substituting the anterior expression in the expresion of $z$ we obtain:

$z = r_1 u_1 + r_2 u_2 + \ldots + r_n u_n + s_1 v_1 x + s_2 v_2 x + \ldots + s_m v_m x$.

In this way we define $G := { \lbrace { u_1 , u_2 , \ldots , u_n , v_1 x, v_2 x , \ldots , v_m x } \rbrace }$. And above we have just proved that $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq {\langle G \rangle}_R$ because any element of $\mathfrak{m}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of $G$.

But that $G \subset \mathfrak{m}$ is easy to check, because the elements of $U$ are all of them into $\mathfrak{m}$ and the remaining are elements of $\left(\mathfrak{m}{:}{\langle x \rangle}_R\right)$ times $x$. By definition they are elements of $\mathfrak{m}$. Then **${\langle G \rangle}_R = \mathfrak{m}$**.

Then $G$ is a finite system generator for $\mathfrak{m}$ with $n+m$ elements of $\mathfrak{m}$. Then $\mathfrak{m} \notin \mathcal{C}$ which is the contradiction expected.

Then the supossition $\mathcal{C} \neq \emptyset$ is false. All the ideals of $R$ are finitely-generated as $R$-mod.

Comment: The statement starting at the 4th line from the end is unclear. Why not consider the ideals $m+(y)$ and $(m:(y))$? See my answer, i have edited.

Comment: I do not realize that was easier than I have done. I correct it now. Thanks.

Comment: Another question to improve is that $U$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$. Do you believe that it was good write the detail?.

Comment: I wish someone make question on the proof, because I do not know if it is readable. If the proof is a few large from the proof in the Theorem 3.4 into the Matsumura's Commutative Rings Theory is because I have tried the proof was not a sketch, that only a few persons understand well, but a complete proof, sufficient to somebody that he/she starts to study Commutative Algebra understand the proof whitout too much effort.

Comment: i) your proof is indeed very long and i doubt whether people are willing to read it ii) writing your own answer based on an answer given by someone else and accepting your own answer is not within the ethics of this community.

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not understand English well, my level is low. I think I will not commit this mistake again. The idea of proof is yours (and of Matsumura), in fact I was asking how to understand it, of course, it is clear. I just wanted to develop it for a full demonstration. Yes, it is too long, but sometimes I have to fully develop a test to make sure I understand it. I think many times the evidence is sketchy, and it is only able to understand that who already knows it well. The last sentence is an truth often verified by me.